# SQL Server : using another table as a 'lookup'

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am selecting some data from a table where one of the columns is a value that defines a person. The value is unique to that person but can appear multiple times in the table.

I have no documentation whatsoever on the db - the details of the person (name etc) are held in another table, but that has a *different* ID column and does not reference the ID in the first table.

There is a *third* table (stay with me!) that contains both the ID from the first table, and the id from the second table. So I'm trying to use this to create a 'link' between the two IDs, so I can then grab the person data I need from the second table. The third table contains many more records than the other two.

I've tried various joins but the data I get back always contains duplicates, and incorrect IDs. I'll try and give an example:

Table 1 (the table I'm querying):

| AgentID | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9000 | 1/1/2022 | 12:00:00 |
| 9000 | 1/2/2022 | 15:00:00 |
| 9001 | 1/1/2022 | 13:00:00 |
| 9001 | 1/2/2022 | 17:00:00 |

Table 2 (the user info):

| UserID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | Fred Bloggs |
| 1001 | John Smith |

Table 3 (the 'link'):

| UserID | AgentID | Other Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 9000 | … |
| 1001 | 9001 |  |
| 1001 | 9001 |  |
| 1000 | 9000 |  |
| 1001 | 9001 |  |
| 1000 | 9000 | etc |

Neither `UserID` or `AgentID` are PKs or FKs in the respective tables (don't ask - we didn't design this....)

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do? It seems there should be but I've hit a brick wall.

Example of what I've tried:

```
SELECT
    table2.name, table1.date,table1.time
FROM
    table2
LEFT JOIN
    table3 ON table3.agentID = table1.agentID
LEFT JOIN
    table2 ON table2.UserID = table3.UserID
```

I've tried inner and right joins as well, same results.

Do I need to be doing some sort of 'nested' join?

Comment: Instead of image links, include DDL (`CREATE TABLE` statements) in you question as code and add the query you tried, even if not working.

Comment: @DanGuzman - apologies - I don't follow the first part of your comment. I've added an example query (although I have tried many).

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Simebaby, not sure what you don't understand. If you don't have the CREATE TABLE scripts, you can generate them by right-clicking on the tables in SSMS object explorer and selecting Script table as-->Create To-->Clipboard. Then edit your question and paste the scripts, formatted as code. Images instead of code tend to attract downvotes here.

Comment: I don't have permissions to create tables on this DB. I can report only. The tables also contain far more data than my examples, most of which I can't post here (including column names).

Comment: Not being able to create tables on the original DB won't prevent you from creating a [mre]. If you can read from the tables, you probably have permission to script them. Even if not, as long as you can create an example in Excel, you can copy-paste that data into new tables on a local server (SQL Server Express or LocalDB) and also try your queries there. If you can't install even that, you'd have to write the scripts manually, which is a bit more work, but better you than counting on whoever is potentially willing to write an answer to jump through those hoops for you.

Comment: If you don't have permissions to create tables, you can declare table variables as substitute for your tables and insert some data into them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **Subquery**, *first* you should join  table1 with distinct value of table3(Link), *second* you should join table2 (UserInfo)with table link. following query

```
SELECT U.Name,
       T.Date,
       T.Time
FROM   table1 t
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT UserID,
                             AgentID
             FROM   table3) L
         ON T.AgentID= L.AgentID
       JOIN table2 U
         ON L.UserID= U.UserID
```

you should change the query per the names of your tables.

Comment: Did it solve your problems?

Comment: Nope :( I get the same output as my example. I can't post a screenshot but the agentid is the same for all rows, even though it is different in the source. The User ID is correct, as is the name, but the rest of the data is duplicated, so (e.g.) date, time, description and duration are the same even though this is invalid data for one of the users.

Comment: I've found the issue and it's actually the source data. I ran the SELECT DISTINCT statement @rf1991 posted in isolation, and the relationship between the UserID and AgentID is not consistent - hence the garbage data being returned. I think I'll have to email the company that 'owns' the database to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: based on your example query, I write the query.can you be more specific about what you want.check for primary keys

Comment: give your final output.

Comment: provide your desired output.

Comment: I think my error with the source data means this approach won't work. In table 3, the same user ID actually points to different Agent IDs - so the relationship isn't what I thought it was, and I don't think I can use that table as an intermediate index. I wouldn't have spotted that without your help though, so thank you.,